# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource when making API call from SharePoint 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint

I wanna break this issue down as simple as possible. I have 3 Applications running on the intranet. The First Application is an Intranet Hosted SharePoint 2019 while the other two (ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API) are applications that run on an in-house application server. From SharePoint 2019, I used JQuery Ajax to make API calls to consume the Service on the application server, which is the server hosting the Web Services. Below is the piece of code that does the API call from SharePoint 2019

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // Call the KPI function here
    getKPI();
});

function getKPI() {
    debugger
    let baseUrl = "https://bny-s-t68/RT_PlatformWebAPI/api/kpi";
    let html = `<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6" align="center" style="background-color:white; padding:2px; border-radius:5px;" 

id='ReportDescription'>Report Description: </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color: white; background-color:#2D6B9F; padding:5px; border-radius:5px; text-align:center !

important;">
    <td>Utilization</td>
    <td>Availability</td>
    <td>Reliability</td>
    <td>Cargoes</td>
    <td>Week</td>
    <td>Year</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color: #000; background-color:#fff; padding:20px; border:solid 1px #red; border-radius:5px; 

text-align:center !important;">
    <td id='Utilization'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='Availability'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='Reliability'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='Cargoes'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='ReportWeek'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='ReportYear'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr></table>`;

    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            var kpi = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data[0]));
            if (data) {
                $("#HseKPI").append(html);

                $("#ReportDescription").append(kpi.ReportDescription);
                $("#ReportYear").append(kpi.ReportYear);
                $("#ReportWeek").append(kpi.ReportWeek);
                $("#Utilization").append(kpi.Utilization).append('%');
                $("#Availability").append(kpi.Availability).append('%');
                $("#Reliability").append(kpi.Reliability).append('%');
                $("#Cargoes").append(kpi.Cargoes);
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    })
}
```

I get the below console error because the API call fails during preflight

[image]

To make sure this sin;t an issue with the API call, I quickly set up an MVC project to consume the API. This time around, I was able to consume the data. I published the solution to the application server and it worked. So is there any reason why SharePoint 2019 is not consuming the endpoint? I there something I may have done wrong? I made sure all the headers were present in the WebApiConfig, Global Asax, I even added the CORs Nugget package and all went well locally and on the server except for SharePoint 2019 not being able to call the endpoint.

Comment: Do you tried it with hosted addins

Comment: @SandunIsuruNiraj Nopes...it's on-premise SharePoint